# What helps a sliced fruit or vegetables oxidize slower?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, redox, food-chemistry

What helps a sliced fruit or vegetables oxidize slower ?

A need of chemical compound to use for the slowing of oxidation... we have tried using a lemon juice it actually helped by 15 mins. However it change the quality of the vegetable after being dip for 10 mins and (*the problem is how do we slow down the oxidation for 10 days without changing the quality of the fruit*) since lemon juice changes the quality of its compound (2-3 days rather).

Comment: I mix cut apples in the oil-based dressing first, then work on the rest of the salad. But 10 days? Many labs are working on this moneymaker.

Comment: Will Vitamin C help? Just guessing..

Comment: On timescale of 10 days oxidation with air is your last problem

Comment: If you soak avacodo pieces in orange juice it makes them last a lot longer

Comment: @bpedit [The magic of biotechnology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_Apples). :P

Comment: @MichaelD.M.Dryden. And modified  atmosphere packaging. And wax!

Comment: http://www.easylunchboxes.com/blog/6-ways-to-stop-fruit-from-browning/

Comment: this suggests ascorbic acid powder could help without altering them, though I don't know if it will work for 10 days. Are you able to refrigerate them?

Answer (score 0):

You can cover the cut pieces with aluminium foil which acts as sacrificial element and prevents oxidation of food.